# how do you read the last line in php and parse out certain columns

Tags: php

I am very new to php. I'd really appreciate all the help here.

I am using sftp to login to a server and get a file. I am only interested in the last line in that file. The last line seperated by tabs. I would like to store the 15, 16, 19 and 20, and 21st col values to 5 different variables. The last line looks like this:

```
7   1   0   59422170     306669 20188 20386     0     0 39787  59981  2014  67796 48953  2  7 90  1  1.81  11.3 12:19:50
```

When I issue this cCurl command the get the file, how would I read the last line in this file and parse out the certain columns in the last line?

```
<?php
$user="user";
$pass="pass";
$c = curl_init("sftp://$user:$pass@server1/vmstat");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
#echo $data;

?>
```

Comment: What is the `15, 16, 19 and 20, and 21st col` ?

Comment: There is [fgetcsv](http://php.net/fgetcsv); Just use `\t` as separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = explode("\n", $data);
$last_line = end($data);
$parts = explode("\t", $last_line);
```

Comment: @Oswalt, thank you for this. But when I do echo to $last_line I dont get anything.

Comment: Is the last line an empty line? or does `end` give you `false`?

Comment: @Frits van Campen, the end seems empty, how would you do -1

Comment: Try `end($data); $second_to_last_line = prev($data);` You might need another `prev`, I'm not sure.

Comment: `if ($last_line === false) {echo 'There is no "last line" in $data'}`

Comment: you can always just `trim()` the file data first

Comment: I did this and was able to get the last line: $size = sizeof($data); 
$last_line=$data[$size-2]; but the pars section is not working. the columns are saprated by space.

Comment: the last_line is space separated and I did this: $parts = explode(" ", $last_line); but when I try to echo $parts[0] through 20, I dont get anything printing.

Comment: @Oswald, I noticed that there may be more space between two values and when I do $parts=explode(" ", $last_line), the size of the parts is greater than it should be due to extra extra space between two values. Quick question how would I replace all instance of space with a comma or something?

Comment: Use `preg_split()` instead of `explode()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why use php?

With input file:

```
7   1   0   59422170     306669 20188 20386     0     0 39787  59981  2014  67796 48953  2  7 90  1  1.81  11.3 12:19:50
```

and command line:

```
tail -n1 myfile | sed 's/\s\s*/ /g' | cut -d' ' -f15,16,19,20,21
```

result is:

```
2 7 1.81 11.3 12:19:50
```

Comment: I need to use php to get the file from remote servers.

Answer (score 0):

### Last line

Might be overkill if the file is small, but wrote [this function](http://www.geekality.net/2011/05/28/php-tail-tackling-large-files/) a while ago. Returns the last n lines of a file/stream.

```
function tail($file, $lines = 10, $buffer = 4096)
{
        if(is_resource($file) && (get_resource_type($file) == 'file' || get_resource_type($file) == 'stream'))
                $f = $file;
        elseif(is_string($file))
                $f = fopen($file, 'rb');
        else
                throw new Exception('$file must be either a resource (file or stream) or a filename.');

        $output = ''; 
        $chunk = '';

        fseek($f, -1, SEEK_END);

        if(fread($f, 1) != "\n")
                $lines -= 1;

        while(ftell($f) > 0 && $lines >= 0)
        {
                $seek = min(ftell($f), $buffer);
                fseek($f, -$seek, SEEK_CUR);

                $output = ($chunk = fread($f, $seek)).$output;
                fseek($f, -mb_strlen($chunk, '8bit'), SEEK_CUR);
                $lines -= substr_count($chunk, "\n");
        }

        while($lines++ < 0)
                $output = substr($output, strpos($output, "\n")+1);

        fclose($f); 
        return $output; 
}
```

### Columns

If tab separated, simply do a split and assign what you want to variables.

```
$columns = explode("\t",$line);

$foo = $columns[15];
...
```